# Networkx graph with different nodes from three lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, networkx

i want to describe you my problem...

I tried to optimize routes with gurobipy and I got active arcs like this:

```
active_arcs=[(0, 2),(0, 4),(0, 11),(1, 24),(2, 7),(3, 1),(4, 5),(5, 3),(6, 0),(7, 6),
(8, 14),(9,6),(10, 0),(11, 13),(12, 9),(13, 12),(14, 15),(15, 16),(16, 17),(17, 18),
(18, 0),(19, 23),(20, 19),(21, 20),(22, 10),(23, 22),(24, 8),(26, 21)]
```

and two lists with indices of addresses:

```
locations= [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23]

gas_stations = [24,25,26,27]
```

now I want to plot a networkx graph...

For every index in active_arcs and in locations I want a blue node with the index.

For every index in active_arcs and in gas stations I want a green node with the index "C" for Charge instead of the index.

In this Example the indices 24 and 26 should be green and "C"

[image]

I tried it like that but I have no idea how to solve it...

```
import networkx
G = networkx.Graph(active_arcs)
labels = dict(zip(G.nodes(), G.nodes()))
networkx.draw_networkx(G,labels=labels, width=1,
                                   node_size=200, font_size=13,
                                   pos=networkx.spring_layout(G))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the values of you labels dict in order to adapt the labels and create a list of color in the order of the nodes of you graph:

```
import networkx

active_arcs=[(0, 2),(0, 4),(0, 11),(1, 24),(2, 7),(3, 1),(4, 5),(5, 3),(6, 0),(7, 6),
(8, 14),(9,6),(10, 0),(11, 13),(12, 9),(13, 12),(14, 15),(15, 16),(16, 17),(17, 18),
(18, 0),(19, 23),(20, 19),(21, 20),(22, 10),(23, 22),(24, 8),(26, 21)]

locations= [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23]

gas_stations = [24,25,26,27]


G = networkx.Graph(active_arcs)

labels = dict(zip(G.nodes(), G.nodes()))
for l in labels.keys():
    if l in gas_stations:
        labels[l] = 'C'
        
colors = []
for n in G.nodes:
    if n in gas_stations:
        colors.append('green')
    else:
        colors.append('blue')
        


networkx.draw_networkx(G,labels=labels, node_color = colors, width=1,
                                   node_size=200, font_size=13,
                                   pos=networkx.spring_layout(G))
```